# Como contar linhas diferentes no R

Tags: r

tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
Material    Fornecedor
1   A
1   B
1   A
1   C
1   C
2   B
2   D
2   E
3   A
3   B
3   C
3   F
3   G
3   A
4   A
```

Preciso criar uma nova coluna de 1 e 0, onde 0 indicará que aquele fornecedor já apareceu naquele material e 1 indicará que o fornecedor apareceu pela primeira vez naquele material. Ou seja, terei a seguinte tabela:

```
Material    Fornecedor  Qtde
1   A   1
1   B   1
1   A   0
1   C   1
1   C   0
2   B   1
2   D   1
2   E   1
3   A   1
3   B   1
3   C   1
3   F   1
3   G   1
3   A   0
4   A   1
```

Como que faço para criar a coluna Qtde? Meu data.frame possui 560.000 linhas.

Answer (score 1):

Segue código para resolução

```
tab <- data.frame(
  Material = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,3), rep(3,6), 4),
  Fornecedor = c("A","B","A","C","C","B","D","E","A","B","C","F","G","A","A")
)

library(dplyr)
tab %>% 
  mutate(Qtde = ifelse(duplicated(.), 0, 1))
```